# Selecting a value from an enum dropdown for multiple objects in a collection ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an enum dropdown that I need to have a pre-selected value for. The issue is that this dropdown represents a property of an object in my viewmodel, and there can be multiples of these objects. For each object in the viewmodel there's a dropdown, and depending on the object, the value in the dropdown needs to be set to something different.

Here's what I'm working with in my view:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <ul>
        @foreach (var filter in Model.GlobalFilters)
        {
            <li class="form-inline">
                <button class="btn btn-primary disabled margin-right">Exclude</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary disabled margin-right">Files</button>
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(
                  x => x.FilterFunctions,
                  filter.Filter.Function.ToString(),
                new { @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle margin-right"})
                <input type="text" class="form-control margin-right" value="@filter.Filter.Parameter" id="FilterParameter"/>
                <button type="button" class="icon-button" style="background-color:transparent">
                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Model:

```
public class ManageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<GlobalExclusionFilter> GlobalFilters { get; set; }

    public FilterFunction FilterFunctions { get; set; }
}
```

The FilterFunctions property is the enum for populating the drop down lists in question.

The IndexFilter class:

```
public class IndexFilter : IIndexFilter, IEquatable<IndexFilter>
{

    private FilterFunction mFunction;
    private string mParameter

    public FilterFunction Function
    {
        get { return mFunction; }
        set
        {
            mFunction = value;
        }
    }

    public string Parameter
    {
        get { return mParameter; }
        set
        {
            mParameter = value;
        }
    }
}
```

A GlobalExclusionFilter is defined by what's called an IndexFilter. This class, as shown above, is defined by a chosen filter function, coupled with a string property which defines what to filter on. Both of these properties need to be reflected in the list of filters. They should also be editable in the same way that adding a new filter would be editable.

I've done a lot of searching today and haven't stumbled across anything that accomplishes what I need. Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: What are your models (including what is `GlobalFilters`)? Your loop make not sense since you cannot create multiple form controls for the same property (i.e. `FilterFunctions`). And your 2nd parameter (`filter.Filter.Function.ToString()`) makes no sense either - that is for generating the text of the `null` label option

Comment: I've given a bit more info that will hopefully clear things up. Please let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't think I've done a great job at describing my problem (I've gone back and tried to clarify a bit more) but I've managed to come up with a solution. So maybe that will help people better understand who come across this in the future (and maybe others will be able to help me describe my issue better as well)...

Anyway, the collection of objects in my viewmodel whose data I need to reflect with a dropdown is an IEnumerable so I decided to just use an enumerator to in the viewmodel to set the selection in the dropdowns for each object.

Here's my viewmodel:

```
public class ManageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<GlobalExclusionFilter> GlobalFilters { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<GlobalExclusionFilter> GlobalFiltersEnumerator { get; set; }
}
```

The enumerator is used in the view to populate the drop down for each element in my collection via linq (which seems like the only way to populate an enum dropdown unfortunately.

Here's my View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul>
            @foreach (var filter in Model.GlobalFilters)
            {
                <li class="form-inline">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary disabled margin-right">Exclude</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary disabled margin-right">Files</button>
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(
                      m => m.GlobalFiltersEnumerator.Current.Filter.Function,
                      new { @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle margin-right" })
                    <input type="text" class="form-control margin-right" value="@filter.Filter.Parameter" id="FilterParameter"/>
                    <button type="button" class="icon-button" style="background-color:transparent">
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                Model.GlobalFiltersEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyway hopefully this clears things up more and helps people in the future! Please let me know if I can clarify further!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18695248)

Comment: This is the complete answer. I achieved what I was asking about...

I must be really bad at explaining things